# What are weak references?

Tags: lua, weak-references

I tried to understand weak tables/weak references but still can't understand anything.

> "*A weak reference is a reference to an object that is not considered by the garbage collector*"

I found this in [Programming in Lua First Edition](https://www.lua.org/pil/17.html), but the next thing it said really confused me

> "*That means that, if an object is only held inside weak tables, Lua will collect the object eventually.*"

Also this information(not from the book though)

> *"An object is considered as "garbage" if it has 0 references"*

```
local t = {x = val} -- x is a weak reference because val isn't considered as "garbage" even after getting removed, x is still a reference of val

val = nil

collectgarbage() --you'd expect {} to be collected

for i, v in pairs(t) do
    print(v) --prints the table
end
```

The object is only held inside a weak table(which is t), but Lua doesn't collect this. I still can print the table, the table isn't got rid by the garbage collector.

This information also got proved by [Lua 5.1 Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.10.2)

> *"In other words, if the only references to an object are weak references, then the garbage collector will collect this object."*

Is there anything wrong with **the information** I gathered or the code I showed? I'm pretty bad at learning things, thus I have to ask many questions.
If yes then please give me right the right information and some specific examples.

**EDIT**: I understood how does weak tables and weak references work now, also I learnt a new thing about table.insert() : I can insert tables with table.insert(), seems amazing.

Comment: in your code example t is not shown to be weak table, you do not set metatable to t and do not put __mode field into metatable.

Comment: oh ok, so I have to make it become a weak table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you have to declare the table as weak (that is, having either weak keys or weak values or both)

```lua
local weak = setmetatable({}, {__mode="v"}) -- Create table weak with weak values
```

Then you can store an object in the table

```lua
table.insert(weak, {"hello", "world"})
```

Since there is no other reference to the object except as a value in the table, it will get collected by the GC the next time it runs. The entire key-value-pair will then be gone from the table and it will be empty, as there were no other paris.